# creating a tree structure from a delimited string xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a input string looks like below

test1->test2->test3

I want to build a tree structure like the below.

-test1 
   +test2

How can I convert the string to tree structure using xslt 2.0.

Comment: Please do not add code in images, but simply as text. More help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I have taken out the images. I have added images for better understanding of the problem, because I couldn't able to place the tree structure without placing an image.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What makes `-test1 +test2` a "tree structure"? And what happened to `test3`?

Comment: The tree structure should look like + test1, then once clicked it should open the clild elements like -test1  +test2 and once test2 is clicked, it should open the last element that is -test1 -test2 and test3. And the process goes on for increased number of elements.

Comment: Maybe first you should figure out what the actual output should be. Since you mention "clicking" it sounds like it's most likely HTML. Manually create the working HTML/CSS/JS/whatever and then you'll have something more specific than "tree structure". You should then look at the `tokenize()` XPath function for splitting your string and processing each token to get the needed output.

Answer (score 0):

The following stylesheet splits the string into a sequence of strings using `tokenize()` and then recursively calls the "nest" template to create an element for the first item in the sequence and then call the template with the remaining strings to generate the nested elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="delimited-input" select="'test1->test2->test3'"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="nest">
            <xsl:with-param name="names" select="tokenize($delimited-input, '->')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="nest" as="element()*">
        <xsl:param name="names" as="xs:string*"/>
        <xsl:if test="exists($names)">
            <xsl:variable name="head" select="$names[position() = 1]"/>
            <xsl:element name="{$head}">
                <xsl:call-template name="nest">
                    <xsl:with-param name="names" select="$names[position() > 1]"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces the following nested element structure:

```
<test1>
   <test2>
      <test3/>
   </test2>
</test1>
```

Assuming that you want to produce HTML, adjust to generate `<div>` or whatever specific elements necessary.