# Making a tree from delimited elements using XSLT

Tags: xslt

The question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840940/creating-a-tree-structure-from-a-delimited-string-xslt-2-0) but slightly more complex...

I need to transform a flat XML like

```
    <XML>
        <A.W>1</A.W>
        <A.X>2</A.X>
        <B.Y>3</B.Y>
        <B.Z>4</B.Z>
        <C>5</C>
    </XML>
```

to a proper tree

```
    <XML>
        <A>
            <W>1</W>
            <X>2</X>
        </A>
        <B>
            <Y>3</Y>
            <Z>4</Z>
        </B>
        <C>5</C>
    </XML>
```

using XSLT

So, the levels of the tree are dot-separated. Ideally with unlimited fold, but could be just the 2-levels one. Thank you!

Comment: "I need" is not a question. What is the *specific**  difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this? Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports.

Comment: What would be the result for two `<A.W>1</A.W><A.W>1</A.W>`?

Comment: high level, 1st transform it to a tree with nested but repeated elements <A><W>1</W></W>....and then transform that tree to group the 'A' level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for starters:

```
<xsl:template match="XML">
   <xsl:for-each-group select="*" 
            group-adjacent="substring-before(local-name(), '.')">
     <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
           <xsl:element name="{substring-after(local-name(), '.')}">
               <xsl:copy-of select="child::node()"/>
           </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: There is one missing curly bracket in `<xsl:element name="{substring-after(local-name(), '.')}">`. Everything else works like a charm. Thanks a lot!!!